# Why is the Actions button missing from Reports on 4.7.x after upgrade

Tags: civireport, actions

After upgrading, several sites are missing the Actions on the Reports

Answer (score 1):

In our case this was because the 4.6.x sites were using

- net.ourpowerbase.reports.advancedfundraising

needed to swop to the newer repo of the code ie

- net.ourpowerbase.report.advancedfundraising (without the 's') from

https://github.com/jmcclelland/net.ourpowerbase.report.advancedfundraising/archive/master.zip

Answer (score 1):

I found this on a site we upgrade to 4.7.27 from about 4.7.21 (although possibly it occurred in an earlier upgrade and we didn't notice because we weren't making any changes to the reports). We were using Extended Report extension and upgrading that fixed this for us.